# Get the returned html from a URL request

Tags: java, html, request

I have this code:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.gooel.com");

        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        //httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
            httpCon.getOutputStream());
        out.write("Resource content");
        out.close();
        // httpCon.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
      httpCon.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can i get the returned html from this connection and print it on screen?
This doesn't work.

Thanks,

Comment: nice url for an example :D

Comment: :D, i know i missed it :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest answer:
[google HttpURLConnection](https://www.google.de/#q=HttpURLConnection%20example)

Use first hit:
[Java: Simple HTTPUrlConnection example](http://digiassn.blogspot.de/2008/10/java-simple-httpurlconnection-example.html)

And you are done!

Comment: nice answer, i always find new ways on how to search google :D,

Comment: how can i add a parameter to the request, if it is a POST request?